# How to build a byte buffer in CFFI?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, cffi

I am retrieving a huge string over HTTP via Curl. Because of this, I can’t call `cffi:foreign-string-to-lisp` in the curl write callback, since not all data of the string is available  at the moment when the callback is called – and calling `cffi:foreign-string-to-lisp` for only parts of the string yields an "invalid UTF-8" error.

Therefore I need to somehow copy the data received as a CFFI pointer to some buffer; with C this would be easy, just use `realloc`. But how can I have some sort of growing buffer in Lisp with CFFI?

```
(cffi:defcallback cb-write :unsigned-int ((ptr :pointer) (size :unsigned-int)
                      (nmemb :unsigned-int) (stream :pointer))
  (let* ((data-size (* size nmemb))
     
    ;; Copy the data from the pointer "ptr" somewhere – it is "data-size" bytes long.
    
    data-size))
```

Comment: I'd just use curl, the program, and capture its standard output.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the problem is that the callback gets a binary data chunk that by itself is not correct UTF8 (boundaries)? If so, is there some reason why you cannot join the binary chunks outside of cffi and then convert it to UTF-8 (either processing as far as you can after each chunk, or when you have all pieces)?

Comment: @TomasZellerin Because I don’t know how to do that. In the meantime, I used a global variable to achieve something similar, by storing the bytes in a list – accessing each byte with `cffi:mem-aref` and `push`ing it into the global. Then I reverse the list, copy it into a vec and finally can convert it into an UTF-8 string. This is highly inefficient of course, but it works for me now.

Comment: You can use vector-push-extend to build a vector from start. This is still not the fastest way (octet by octet copy instead of bigger blocks), but cffi copies string in same way.

Just to be sure, the text you want is really utf8 and not ascii, right? Otherwise, setting different default encoding wuld help.

Anyway, unless you have specific requirements I would use a native implentation CL implementation or as Kaz said.

Btw, I can see that in https://cl-curl.common-lisp.dev/ the author used some .c code for this, but then moved to Drakma anyway.

Comment: @TomasZellerin For me this is a learning experience; I am new to lisp in general, and this small program helped me to apply and exercise some of the concepts I have read about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of buffer (that is probably unsigned-byte vector, so an array) can be changed in CL with [ADJUST-ARRAY](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/f_adjust.htm). If the array was declared adjustable (with `:adjustable t`), then this function returns the original array and adjusts it, otherwise it may return a new array. If only new-dimensions and an initial-element argument are supplied, the content of the array is "kept".

The adjust-array might be called "automatically" when needed if your vector is fillable (with :fill-pointer t) and you add elements using `VECTOR-PUSH-EXTEND`.

This should answer question as directly asked. In the presented context I would probably want to process data as we go to prevent creating huge binary data (assuming they can be gigabytes), but I have no good solution for this with CFFI and UTF-8 conversion functions I know about (maybe creating gray stream from binary data and processing it as stream source, but it is overly complicated). So in the end, I believe using native HTTP client implementation, or even as Kaz suggested reading output of curl process, might be easier and in fact even faster.

If you know that the data are (for example) just ASCII and not UTF-8 you can skip all these problems by changing default encoding.

Incidentally, I would say you found bug in [CFFI documentation](https://cffi.common-lisp.dev/manual/html_node/Tutorial_002dCallbacks.html) where they boldly use `foreign-string-to-lisp` in this context, so you may try to discuss with the authors - but maybe they just strived for simplicity.